# AJAX Length Limitations

Tags: javascript, ajax

I understand that the maximum length for an AJAX call using GET is 2083 (at least with IE6.)

Is there any such limitation when doing an AJAX call using POST? I've never used a POST with an AJAX call so I'm not even sure what other differences there might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is no arbitrary byte limit to posts.  However sending huge amounts of data up or down from a web application could cause problems with users, especially if they have a capped bandwidth plan.

Comment: There are no arbitrary client-side byte limits to POSTs. There are (tweakable) server-side limits.

Comment: I added +1 to another comment since it was technically more accurate. But I agree with TJ's sentiment re: user experience.

Answer (score 5):

That depends on your server.

IIS/ASP.Net (by default) has a limit on the size of a post body, (about 2 MB). But this can be changed using the configuration files.

For normal AJAX usage, you will not run into trouble. If you start uploading files, then you will reach the limits very easy.

Comment: Good answer. Apache, nginx, and PHP all have their own tweakable POST limits.